# C | Segregate even and odd nodes in a Linked List

Tags: c

i need a little fix in my code
the function void sort_list(struct Node* head) divide the list to 2 lists: odd numbers and even numbers . then marge the 2 lists back to one list when the even numbers in the left and the odd numbers in the right.
everything works except that the original list don't update in the main.
i don't wont to return the new list. the function need to be void.
maybe i need to send the list in different way but i don't know how.
thanks for help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node* Create_list(int size) {
    struct Node* head = NULL, *temp;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0;i<size;i++) {
        int x = rand() % 10 + 1;
        temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        temp->data = x;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
    }
    return head;
}

void print_list(const struct Node* head) {
    struct Node* temp=head;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%4d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void free_list(struct Node* head) {
    struct Node* to_free = head;
    while (to_free != NULL) {
        head = head->next;
        free(to_free);
        to_free = head;
    }
}

void sort_list(struct Node* head) {
    struct Node* head_odd, *head_even, *temp;
    head_odd = head_even = NULL;
    while (head != NULL) {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        if ((temp->data) % 2 == 0) {
            temp->next = head_even;
            head_even = temp;
        }
        else {
            temp->next = head_odd;
            head_odd = temp;
        }

    }
    head = head_even;
    while (head_even->next != NULL) {
        head_even = head_even->next;
    }
    head_even->next = head_odd;
}

void main() {
    struct Node* list = Create_list(6);
    print_list(list);
    sort_list(list);
    print_list(list);
    free_list(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C uses pass-by-value. So this:

```
void sort_list(struct Node* head) {
```

followed by

```
    sort_list(list);
```

will pass the value of `list` to the function.

Any change you make to `head` inside the function are local to head, i.e. will not change the value of `list` in main.

Use a double pointer like:

```
void sort_list(struct Node** head) {
....
    *head = ....


sort_list(&list);
```

or return a pointer like:

```
struct Node* sort_list(struct Node* head) {
....
    return head;


list = sort_list(list);
```