# Segregating even and odd nodes in a Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to segregate even and odd nodes in a Linked List in C.

Example:

Original list: 3,1,8,2,5,6
After change: 8,2,6,3,1,5

I have a problem when the head list data is an odd number, it is cutting out the even numbers.

Example:

Original list: 3,1,8,2,5,6
After change: 3,1,5

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;            // store information
    struct Node * next;  //referance to the next node
}Node;

Node * create(Node * L, int value)
{
    Node *current = L ,* new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)); // create and allocate a node 
    new_node->data = value;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if (L == NULL)
    {
        L = new_node;
        current = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        while (current->next != NULL)
            current = current->next;
        current->next = new_node;
        current = new_node;
    }
    return L;
}

Node * Change_Even_Odd(Node * L)
{
        Node *oddhead = NULL, *evenhead = NULL, *lastodd = NULL, *lasteven = NULL, *current = L;
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            // if current is even node
            if (current->data % 2 == 0)
            {
                if (evenhead == NULL)
                {
                    evenhead = current;
                    lasteven = current;
                }
                else
                {
                    lasteven->next = current;  // to connect the node to the list in the end
                    lasteven = current;  // final list
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // if current is odd node
                if (oddhead == NULL)
                {
                    oddhead = current;
                    lastodd = current;
                }
                else
                {
                    lastodd->next = current;
                    lastodd = current;
                }

            }
            current = current->next;
        }

            if (evenhead != NULL) // to put the even node in the head list
                L = evenhead;
            if (lasteven != NULL)  // link the odd nodes to the even nodes
                lasteven->next = oddhead;
            if (lastodd != NULL)  //end of list
                lastodd->next = NULL;

        return L;

}


void Print_List(Node * head)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%4d", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node * list = NULL;  //empty linked list
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i, size = rand() % 10 + 1;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        list = create(list, rand() % 10 + 1);
    printf("%d\n",size);
    Print_List(list);
    printf("\n");
    Change_Even_Odd(list);
    Print_List(list);
    printf("\n");   
}
```

Comment: It seems there is a problem in other parts.

Comment: But if i am start with even number the result is o.k
Example:
Original : 4,3,2
After: 4,2,3

Comment: @edenv3: You can edit your post if you want to include further code. It isn't very readable as a comment.

Comment: @M Oehm: I edit the comment, thank you.

Comment: @edenv3 That is no reason. Are you using return values? E.g. Like `L = Change_Even_Odd(L);`

Comment: Your function `Change_Even_Odd()` looks like it should work, and I hacked up a quick linked list implementation to test it: it did work, giving the new list `8, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5`. Can you provide a more complete code example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C | Segregate even and odd nodes in a Linked List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41058976/c-segregate-even-and-odd-nodes-in-a-linked-list)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the posted code doesn't produce the problem stated. See http://ideone.com/bYJd9U

Comment: I additional the reset of the code, you think the problem is there? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: `Change_Even_Odd(list);` should be `list = Change_Even_Odd(list);` (I already pointed out.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

`Change_Even_Odd(list);` should be `list = Change_Even_Odd(list);` (I already pointed out.)
                    – BLUEPIXY